# How to get validation pattern from Google Form item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

In Google Forms, a question/item of class [TextItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item) can have a [validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation) pattern set (i.e., the response must match the pattern to be accepted by the form) by doing something like:

```
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .requireTextMatchesPattern(my_regex_pattern)
  .build();
textItem.setValidation(textValidation);
```

I would like to read that pattern from an existing textItem (in order to have a script go through several questions with unique patterns and save them), but I cannot find any references to relevant methods or properties for validation rules, e.g. (made-up examples):

```
var existing_pattern = textItem.getTextMatchesPattern();
```

or

```
var existing_patern = textItem.getValidation.getTextMatchesPattern();
```

From what I can see, it looks like this is not actually possible, but that seems quite strange. Am I missing something?

**Note**: Using the Web interface, it's trivial to get the pattern for a given question/item. I'm specifically asking how to get it through a script.

Comment: Also explain exactly why you need access to the pattern?

Comment: @TheMaster, I have a large number of items with unique patterns, and I wanted to have a script export them to a separate sheet.

Comment: so do you intent to restrict the user to fill out a field with only a specific pattern, or do you want to study the pattern text once they have filled them out.

Comment: if the text validation is too restricted. you can choose to not put text validation here. Instead study the pattern when you are getting the response after form submission. there you would have a lot more freedom

Comment: @Narendra, restrict: each question has a very precise definition of accepted answers. I'm just trying to read that pattern.

Comment: @Ratler were you able to solve it? I have found GApps Script to provide very limited methods and you have to do the thing within that. May be you can try talking to google support if you really need that google form out in that specified way.

Comment: @Narendra: did not solve it, and gave up at some point. I don't have a paid account to get Google support, and using the G Suite forum in the past has proven to be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported to Google issue tracker: [#80092816](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80092816)

You may add a +1 or star this issue to let Google know that you want this to be fixed soon.